# Check if element exists in array if not print not found

Tags: javascript, arrays, element

I am new to JS. I have task:

> Given names and phone numbers, assemble a phone book that maps friends' names to their respective phone numbers. You will then be given an unknown number of names to query your phone book for. For each queried, print the associated entry from your phone book on a new line in the form name=phoneNumber; if an entry for is not found, print Not found instead.

**Note:** Your phone book should be a Dictionary/Map/HashMap data structure.

Input Format

The first line contains an integer, , denoting the number of entries in the phone book.
Each of the  subsequent lines describes an entry in the form of  space-separated values on a single line. The first value is a friend's name, and the second value is an -digit phone number.

After the lines of phone book entries, there are an unknown number of lines of queries. Each line (query) contains a  to look up, and you must continue reading lines until there is no more input.

Note: Names consist of lowercase English alphabetic letters and are first names only.

Here is my code. But i cant check name exists in array or not. Js includes didnt work?

```
function processData(input) {
//Enter your code here
const  n = parseInt(input);
const  d = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    var line = input.split('\n').splice(i,1);
    let x = line[0].split(" ");
    d[x[0]] = x[1];
}
console.log(d)
let m = n;
while (true){
    try{
        name = input.split('\n').splice(m+1,1);
        if ( d.includes(name)){
            console.log(name,'=',d[name])
        } else console.log('Not found')
        m +=1;
    }
    catch(err){
        break
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please add a [mcve] that shows the actual problem.

Comment: An example of your input would be very helpfull

Comment: 3
sam 99912222
tom 11122222
harry 12299933
sam
edward
harry

Comment: it is a simple input

Comment: Sample Output

sam=99912222
Not found
harry=12299933

Answer (score 0):

`name` is the result of a `splice` on an array, which means it's an array, but you've filled `d` with strings, so `d.includes(name)` is looking for a newly-created array inside an array of strings. No array is ever equal to a string (without conversion, which `includes` doesn't do).

If you meant `name` to be the entry you removed from the array with `splice` (since it returns an array of removed entries), you'd need to use `[0]` on the end to get it:

```
name = input.split('\n').splice(m+1,1)[0];
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^
```

I haven't gone through the code to look for other issues, but that will at least look for a string in the array of strings rather than looking for an array in the array of strings.

---

Side note: You appear to be relying on getting an error to stop your loop, but beware that accessing beyond the end of an array is not an error in JavaScript, you just get the value `undefined`.